# Computing naive algebraic singular homology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory

I'm not sure if this counts as research level, since it might just be an expression of my ignorance. But anyway.

Let $\Delta^n_A = Spec(A[X_0, \dots, X_n]/\sum X_i - 1)$ denote the standard algebraic simplex over $A.$ These assemble into the standard cosimplicial affine scheme $\Delta_A^\bullet.$ Hence, given any scheme $X,$ one may define a simplical set $Sing_\bullet(X)(A) = Hom(\Delta^\bullet_A, X)$ and then, taking the associated chain complex, we may define the *naive algebraic homology groups* as

$H_*(X)(A) = h_* \mathbb{Z}Sing_\bullet(X)(A),$

where we do the usual thing of taking the free simplicial abelian group on $Sing_\bullet$ and alternating sums of face maps as differentials.

For more on the construction, compare: [References for the "nerve of an algebraic variety"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/166129/references-for-the-nerve-of-an-algebraic-variety)

As is pointed out in that answer, this particular construction is not in general well-behaved. (The good version is to use morphisms into infinite symmetric products, which then computes singular homology.) However: can we compute these naive groups for any spaces at all? What I have come up with:

- $H_0(\mathbb{G}_m)(A) = A^\times,$ $H_n(\mathbb{G}_m) = 0$ for $n>1$ because $\mathbb{G}_m$ is A^1-invariant.
- $H_0(\mathbb{A}^n)(A) = \mathbb{Z}$ and the higher groups vanish - because $\mathbb{A}^n$ are algebraically contractible [I haven't checked this in detail.]
- $H_0(\mathbb{P}^1)(k) = \mathbb{Z}$ for any field $k$

But these observations are all essentially trivial. Using work of cazanave on naive homotopy classes of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1,$ one may compute $H_0(\mathbb{P}^1)(k[X]),$ but this is already fairly non-trivial.

**Perhaps some concrete questions:** Can anyone compute $H_n(\mathbb{P^1})(k)$ or $H_n(PGL_2)(k),$ for some $k$ or $n>0$? Are these groups zero for $n$ sufficiently large?

Comment: In your remark on the work of Cazanave, you probably mean to compute $H_0(\mathbb{P}^1)(R)$ where $R$ is the coordinate ring of the affine variety $GL_2/(\mathbb{G}_m\times\mathbb{G}_m)$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, we have $Hom(A^1 \times \Delta^n, P^1) = Hom(P^1 \times \Delta^n, P^1)$ and so $H_0(P^1)(k[t])$ computes unpointed naive homotopy classes of endomorphisms.

Comment: By construction, $H_\ast(X)(A)$ is $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant. It is possible to write down explicit contractions (if I remember correctly, the paper of Morel and Voevodsky is one place where this is written down). So $H_0(\mathbb{P}^1)(k[T])\cong\mathbb{Z}$ again. The identification of evaluation of the singular resolution over $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$ does not work. There is a natural restriction map. This takes the identity of $\mathbb{P}^1$ to the natural inclusion $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$. The former is not nullhomotopic, but the latter is (via the obvious homotopy).

Comment: Continued: another way to see the problem is translating the claim into classical topology. We can compactify $\mathbb{R}$ by $S^1$, but $Hom(\mathbb{R}\times\Delta^\bullet,S^1)$ is surely not equivalent to $Hom(S^1\times\Delta^\bullet,S^1)$.

Comment: To elaborate on my first comment: the natural projection $GL_2(\mathbb{G}_m\times\mathbb{G}_m)\to\mathbb{P}^1$ is an $\mathbb{A}^1$-weak equivalence so that homotopy classes of maps from this affine variety to $\mathbb{P}^1$ are homotopy classes of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: As in topology, this naïve $H_0$ is the free abelian group on the naïve $\pi_0$. Therefore, the computation of naive homotopy classes of endomorphisms of $\mathbf P^1$ gives you the computation of $H_0(\mathcal F_n)$ where $\mathcal F_n$ is the scheme of pointed degree $n$ rational functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has not been so much research on $\operatorname{Sing}(X)(A)$, and most of it concentrated on its homotopy. Nevertheless, some things are known:

- Among the first results are those by Jardine in a series of papers at the beginning of the 80s, see [the first five entries on his list of publications.](http://www.math.uwo.ca/~jardine/cv/jardine-pub.html) You can also check [Jardine's thesis.](http://www.math.uwo.ca/~jardine/papers/preprints/Jardine-thesis.pdf) From his results you get that $H_0(G)(k)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ for a group $G$ whose $k$-points are generated by unipotent elements. He also proved $H_1(SL_n)(k)\cong K_2(k)$ for $n\geq 3$ and $H_1(Sp_{2n})(k)\cong K_2(k)$ for $k$ algebraically closed.
- Very classical results of Rector and Gersten identify the homotopy of $\operatorname{Sing}(GL)(R)$ with algebraic K-theory if $R$ is a regular ring (basically a consequence of homotopy invariance for algebraic K-theory). 
  You can read about this in Chapter 4 of Jardine's thesis.
- The results of Jardine are now know to hold more generally. For $G$ isotropic reductive and $R$ a regular ring, $H_0(G)(R)\cong\mathbb{Z}[G(R)/E(R)]$ by [unstable homotopy for $K_1$-functors, a result of Stavrova.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4664) This relates $H_0$ with Whitehead groups. For $G$ isotropic reductive and $k$ a field, $H_1(G)(k)\cong H_2(G(k),\mathbb{Z})$ is proved in [my paper with Konrad Voelkel,](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2364v1.pdf) as a consequence of homotopy invariance in one variable for homology of isotropic reductive groups.
- The identification $H_1(G)(k)\cong H_2(G(k),\mathbb{Z})$ can also be derived from an $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy point of view. This is explained in Morel's ["$\mathbb{A}^1$-algebraic topology over a field", Section 6.2](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~morel/Prepublications/A1TopologyLNM.pdf) and [in this paper.](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=7606992)
- Another result which can be deduced from the results in Morel's book: the spaces $\mathbb{A}^n\setminus 0$ have the affine Brown-Gersten property so that the $\mathbb{A}^1$-$(n-2)$-connectivity implies $H_i(\mathbb{A}^n\setminus 0)(k)=0$ for $1\leq i\leq n-2$ and $H_{n-1}(\mathbb{A}^n\setminus 0)(k)\cong K^{MW}_n(k)$.
- If we allow $X$ to be more general than a scheme, we can also say something about classifying spaces of algebraic groups. The very classical results mentioned above can be reformulated as follows: homotopy invariance of algebraic K-theory implies that for $R$ a regular ring $H_n(BGL)(R)\cong H_n(BGL(R),\mathbb{Z})$. On the left is the naive algebraic singular homology of the infinite Grassmannian, and on the right is group homology of the infinity general linear group over $R$, viewed as discrete group.
  It is a subject of current investigations if an isomorphism such as this holds for linear algebraic groups (related to weak homotopy invariance). Weak homotopy invariance and its current status are discussed  [in my MO-answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163250/) and some results related to computation of $H_3(BSL_2)(k)$ can be found  [in my paper with Kevin Hutchinson](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3069).